# C Reader Writer Program, One reader isnt reading all the data

Tags: c, reader, writer

I am working on a reader/writer program where there is one writer to n readers. I am having an issue where if multiple readers are in, like the screenshot posted below, then the entire message from shared memory isnt displayed.

**Output**:

Enter a Message: Test

Reader1: Test

Reader2: Test

Writer: test test

Reader1: test

Reader2: test test

**Writer**:

[image]

**Readers**:

[image]

I have tried to add a count variable because I assume that the writers turn is being flagged before all readers have the ability to print and its making the writer then exit the nested while() in the writer and stop the readers from printing.

Any suggestions on to make the readers both print, whether it be a flag or some sort of count? Attached below are also screenshots of the writer and reader loops.

Reader:

```
int main() {
    DataShared data;
    data.turn = 0;
    signal(SIGINT, sigHandler);

    //generates key
    key = ftok("mkey",65);

    //returns an identifier in mId
    if ((mId = shmget(key, SIZE, IPC_CREAT|S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR)) < 0){
    perror("shared memory error");
    exit(1);
    }

    // shmat to attach to shared memory
    if((mPtr = shmat(mId, 0, 0)) == (void*) -1) {
    perror("Can't attach\n");
    exit(1);
    }


    while(1) {
        // request critical section
        while(!data.turn && data.count == 0) {
        //not time for the reader, check if token is changed.
            memcpy(&data, mPtr, sizeof(DataShared));
        }

        data.count++;

        // enter critical section
        usleep(1);
        fprintf(stderr, "Read from memory: %s\n", data.message);
        usleep(1);
        // leave critical section

        data.count--;

        while(data.count > 0){
            ;
        }

        data.turn = 0;
        memcpy(mPtr, &data, sizeof(DataShared));
    };

    return 0;
}
```

Writer:

```
int main() {
    DataShared data;
    data.turn = 0;
    data.count = 0;
    signal(SIGINT, sigHandler);

    key = ftok("mkey",65);

    if((shmId = shmget(key, SIZE, IPC_CREAT|S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR)) < 0 ) {
        perror("Error creating shared memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if((shmPtr = shmat(shmId, 0, 0)) == (void*) -1) {
        perror("Can't attach\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(1) {
        while (data.turn) {
            memcpy(&data, shmPtr, sizeof(DataShared));
        }

        // enter critical section
        printf("Enter a message: \n" );
        fgets(data.message, 1024, stdin);


        // leave critical section
        printf("Message written to memory: %s\n", data.message);
        data.turn = 1;
        memcpy(shmPtr, &data, sizeof(DataShared));
    };

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please remove the images and replace with the text.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I am attempting to do this without semaphores or threads.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Wouldn't that never change the turn from the writer to the reader because flag would never be saved to shared memory?

Comment: I don't understand the scheduling here.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie A writer posts a message to the shared memory, it is then consumed by n readers, they then flag to the writer that its his turn to write again.  Repeat.

Comment: Who sets control to the reader(s) and who sets control to the writer? They are all in an infinite loop. Are there multiple threads?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie its on an infinite loop until the interup is called using `ctrl-c` in which `shmctl` is called and the program exits.

Comment: Please show us your main, where you start the readers and writer.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the explanation of your observation, but what you do is fishy.

You have multiple processes and the OS schedules each process.

First, there is no guarantee that all readers will read the message. It is very well possible that one reader finishes, sets the flag to 0 and copies the data back to shared memory before another reader had a chance to read the data.

Then your `data.count`. It starts with the local variable `data` of the writer. there you do not initialize `data.count` so it has an indeterminate value. In the readers you set it to 0 but it will be overwritten with the value from shared memory (the indeterminate value). You do a ++, later a -- and then wait for it to become 0. How would that ever become zero? That reader could wait forever.

Comment: The first issue you pointed out is the reason I added the count, this was so that I tested to make sure all readers printed before the writer could then go again. The issue with the count variable in the current way its implemented is also known and I tested initializing it in the Writer again but no luck. This problem is definitely getting the best of me :)

Comment: I don't see you initialize `data.count` in the writer.

Comment: Updated the question to where `data.count` is initialized in writer

Comment: OK. Following `data.count++;`, shouldn't you copy it back to shared memory? Otherwise no-one will see it. And that may cause other synchronization problems....

Comment: Does `memcpy` on shared memory guarantee atomicity?

Comment: I tried to write it back to shared memory after the `data.count++` but it ends up making one of the readers go into the busy loop and never come back out. and to answer your second question, I honestly do not know

Comment: @Striker If you go through all the `memcpy()` documentation you can find, do you see any mention at all of the copy being atomic?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I see that it is mentioned it is not atomic